# Achieving additional column that states in and out at time of the procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query which give me the below results for which I need to add another column which denotes In and Out during procedure

```
DECLARE @start datetime, @end datetime

SELECT @start = '10/01/2021'
SELECT @end = '10/4/2021';

WITH list AS
( 
    SELECT
        c.lastname + ', ' + c.FirstName Doctor,
        COUNT(ID) count
    FROM
        Carecenter c
    WHERE
        c.LastName IS NOT NULL 
        AND (c.HIDDEN IS NULL OR c.HIDDEN <> 1) 
        AND c.Procedure_Date BETWEEN @start AND @end
    GROUP BY
        LastName, FirstName
)
SELECT
    c.lastname + ', ' + c.FirstName Doctor,
    procedure_name,
    COUNT(procedure_name) [Procedure count], 
    l.count [patient count]
FROM
    Carecenter c
LEFT JOIN
    list l ON l.Doctor = c.lastname + ', ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + Title
WHERE
    Procedure_Date BETWEEN @start AND @end
GROUP BY
    c.lastname, FirstName, l.count, Procedure_Name
```

And the result is:

```
Doctor  procedure_name  Procedure count patient count
-----------------------------------------------------
Dia MD      D2              1               2
Siri MD     C1              2               2
Google MD   A1              2               2
Alexa MD    I2              1               1
```

I tried to include the `Patient_Class 'Inpatient\Outpatient'` so to differentiate the classes on the count.

Expected results:

```
Doctor  procedure_name  Procedure count patient count   patient_class
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Dia MD      D2              1               2           Outpatient
Dia MD      D2              1               2           Outpatient
Siri MD     C1              2               2           Outpatient
Siri MD     C1              2               2           Inpatient
Google MD   A1              2               2           Inpatient
Google MD   A1              2               2           Outpatient
Alexa MD    I2              1               1           Inpatient
```

How can I achieve the above results by adding the column `patient_class` in the above query?

Comment: In your desired results above, you are grouping by paitent_class, however, you have the SUM of all patient_class values. For example, Google MD A1 Inpatient and Outpaitent should logically only have a patient count of 1, not 2. Are you sure you don't want the sums to fall within the aggregated values and not the whole partition? Also your second where clause is redundant.

Comment: Please help us to help you with a [mcve], perhaps as a https://dbfiddle.uk

Answer (score 0):

I bet you can return the desired results within one query using a partitioned count aggerate. It is hard to derive from your results how you want the [patient count] values to fall. If you want to show the total number of in/out patient for all records in the group then you need to change the last COUNT() to be partitioned over the paitent_class, however, I think you are looking for the count of inpatient and outpatients within the grouping.

```
select 
    c.lastname+', '+c.FirstName Doctor,
    procedure_name
    COUNT(*) OVER PARTITION BY(procedure_name) [Procedure count],
    COUNT(*) [patient count]
from 
    Carecenter c
where 
    c.LastName is not null and (c.HIDDEN is null or c.HIDDEN <>1) and c.Procedure_Date between @start and @end
group by 
    LastName,
    FirstName,
    Procedure_Name,
    patient_class
```